# Find the count of name in the table which may not contain a character 'a' or 'A' given a correct Name using the sql functions

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-function

In table `StudentData`, containing columns
`(ID, Name, City)`,
there was an error in the keyboard used for entering student names. It’s ‘A’ key was not working properly, and sometimes the letter ‘A’ or ‘a’ did not get typed. So Rahul got entered as Rhul, Sanjay got entered as Snjy. Write a function that takes as input a valid name, and return the total number of students with
that name (with our without correct entry for ‘a’)

Here is a code i wrote

```
DELIMITER $$
create function myfun(nameInput varchar(50)) RETURNS int DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
DECLARE count int;
select COUNT(*) INTO count from StudentData where name = nameInput;

return count;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

the above code does not consider the names which don't have the character 'a' or 'A'.
how do i write a logic for the given question

Comment: The last 2 selects are pointless (and are not terminated) , use = instead of like and consider OR

Comment: yes they are but what do i write after OR do need to write a REGX to check the string?